# Update file with Git on Windows

Tags: windows, git

I recent installed Git and I'm trying to update a file using this command:
(On windows 7)

```
git add Probe.txt
```

But it says "*fatal: pathspec 'probe' did not match any files*" 
I'm in the directory which the file is. In fact, if I try `git status` I get "*modified: Probe.txt*".

How should I update my file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `git add .` which will add everything.  Not sure why the specific filename isn't working, but this definitely should.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're actually entering a space after "Probe" for some reason, observe:

```
~% cd /tmp
/tmp% mkdir foo
/tmp% cd foo
foo% git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/foo/.git/
foo% git add probe .txt
fatal: pathspec 'probe' did not match any files
foo%
```

I'm not on Windows at the moment but I think you can get the idea.

If you're pretty sure it's not the case, please re-try your command after setting

```
set GIT_TRACE=1
```

and update your question by the output of `git add Probe.txt` so we could guess further.